# Formally show that $MLE_{unconstrained} \ge MLE_{constrained}$

Tags: maximum-likelihood

This makes perfect sense - If a model doesn't even assume some structure on the data, then for every value of a predictor, e.g. $x_i$, the MLE is simply the point in that position $\hat \mu_i = y_i$ (or the average of all points with the same predictor).

[image]

Yet if you impose some structure on the data, say a linear line, your MLE will be shifted:

[image]

Question is - how do I formalize this in the language of Math?

Comment: If you're applying different statistical models, why would you get the same mle? Do you just want a result that says something about how different the two mles will be?

Comment: @jcken you wouldn't get the same MLE, as you are now constraining the model. If you have a 1000 points but only, say, a linear regression, you are basically saying find me the line which maximizes the likelihood. If you have a polynom, you are saying find me a polynomial that maximizes the likelihood. But in all these cases you would reduce the likelihood than if you had 1000 variables, and simply say "for each data point just center the distribution around it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $B \subseteq A$, then $$\max_{x \in A} f(x) = \max \left( \max_{x \in B} f(x), \max_{x \in A \setminus B} f(x) \right) \ge \max_{x \in B} f(x)$$
So if $B$ is the set of elements in $A$ that satisfy an additional constraint, then $B \subseteq A$, and the maximum of any function $f$ over the subset $B$ cannot be larger than the maximum of $f$ over the unconstrained set $A$.

To apply this to maximum likelihood estimation, we are really trying to compare two sets of functions: $A$ is a starting set of functions, and $B$ is a subset of the functions in $A$ that satisfy an additional constraint. Then $x \in A$ is a function, and $f(x)$ is the likelihood of the observed data using the function $x$ as a model for that data. In practice, we usually parametrize these sets of functions with a parameter $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and think about $\tilde{A}$ being the set of parameters that parametrize the functions in $A$, and $\tilde{B}$ being the set of parameters that parametrize the functions in $B$.

For example, we could let $A$ be the set of polynomial functions of degree 3 or less, and we could let $B$ be the set of linear functions. Hence $B \subseteq A$. If we wanted to work with the parameters instead, we can parametrize the set of polynomials of degree 3 or less by a vector $\theta = (\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)$ which corresponds to the function $g(t) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \beta_2 t^2 + \beta_3 t^3$. Here, $\tilde{A} = \mathbb{R}^4$, and the constrained set $\tilde{B} = \{ \theta \in \tilde{A} : \beta_2 = \beta_3 = 0 \}$, and of course $\tilde{B} \subseteq \tilde{A}$.

**Addendum**: Note that you cannot talk about maximum likelihood estimation without defining a likelihood function, so let's think about how the likelihood function in Case A could be defined.

The picture suggests that there *is* some structure being imposed on the data: Gaussians don't come from the aether, so there is some assumption behind the Gaussians drawn at each x-value, and each of the Gaussians also seems to have the same standard deviation (but where does that number come from?). The Gaussians are also displayed only along the y-axis without any along the x-axis, so it seems like the picture is saying that the x-values are fixed (non-random) and given. All of these are assumptions about how we are modeling the data and should be clearly stated.

An unconstrained model is really an "every function" model rather than a "no function" model. Assuming the four $x$-values from the picture are fixed, the set of functions $A$ is all functions $f : \{ x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \} \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. those with domain consisting of the $x$-values for the four given points. You could parametrize this class of function using four parameters $\mu = \{ \mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3, \mu_4 \}$, each of which represents the output $f(x_i) = \mu_i$ of the function. To define the likelihood function, you then need to assume something about the probability of observing the given $y$-values $\{ y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4 \}$ for a given parameter $\mu$. If you want to assume that the probability density for each of the $y_i$'s is normally distributed with a fixed standard deviation $\sigma > 0$ as the picture suggests, then $p(y_i | \mu_i) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma)(y_i)= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left[ -\left( \frac{y_i - \mu_i}{\sigma} \right)^2 \right]$. Now if we also assume independence, we can write the likelihood function as $L(\mu) = \prod_{i = 1}^4 p(y_i | \mu_i)$, which is maximized when $\mu_i = y_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$.

Now that the assumptions are clearly stated, note that this is still a particular instance of the general claim that $B \subseteq A \Rightarrow \max_{x \in A} f(x) \ge \max_{x \in B} f(x)$, because we can write any linear function in terms of the same parameters $\mu$ (The $\mu_i$'s simply have to satisfy the constraint that the four points $(x_i, \mu_i)$ are collinear).

Comment: cool, but notice that A in my case is basically a "no-function", or a discrete function that gives each observation its own Gaussian. How would you define it?

Comment: I hope I answered this in the addendum to my answer.